# aSwiftUI calling background causes infinite re-render crash

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

Why does the following SwiftUI code produce a crash when calling `background(Color.white)`? (100% reproducible for me)

```
    struct ContentView: View {     
        var body: some View {         
            let _ = print("rendering")         
            background(Color.white)     
        } 
    }
```

I (now) understand this is not the way to set a background color, but the behavior still seems unexpected. The console prints "rendering" ~30 times, then crashes. Shouldn't SwiftUI produce a warning or an error here?

`0x185a24fc8 <+8>:    stp    x28, x27, [sp, #0x90]`

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16d037fd0)`

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `self.background` inside the `body` of your `View`.

The `background` view modifier modifies the view it is applied to, in this case, `self`, since it is called on `self`. This creates an infinite loop, since to apply `background`, the system tries to evaluate `body`, which then calls `background` again.

You either need to call `background` on another `View`, such as a

```
Color.clear // can replace this with any other View, such as Text("Hello world")
    .background(Color.white)
```

or you even better, you should simply return `Color.white` in your `body` if you want to return a white color.

```
struct ContentView: View {     
    var body: some View {         
        Color.white  
    } 
}
```

The `Color.clear` example is equivalent to simply returning `Color.white`, so don't use that in production code, I've just included it as an example.